# Private cocoapod in development fails to lint when attempting to access private dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

As a quick intro, all of the cocoapods involved are held in private repositories.

Some general information:

- Cocoapods version 1.9.1 (latest as of today)
- Xcode 11.3.1
- Command line tools Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504)
- Swift 5.0
- macOS 10.15.3

I have successfully configured a private spec repo that two Cocoapod have been published to. My local repository has been updated with the steps that Cocoapod publishes, and I verified that the expected `podspec` files were present.

```
pod repo add my_repo https://gitsite.com/my-spec-repo.git
```

And then verified on my machine:

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/my_repo
pod repo lint .
```

I also visually verified the proper files & versions were present.

Then I add the source to a consuming apps `Podfile` like so:

```
source 'https://gitsite.com/my-spec-repo/'
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
```

After doing all of these steps, everything works great and I can install & use the pod. Thus, all is well to this point.

I am now building a new private Cocoapod that must consume one of my private pods.

In my `podspec` file, I have marked the dependency:

```
s.dependency 'my_private_pod', '~> 1.2.3'
```

I have also included an entry in my `Podfile` for the example app.

```
pod 'my_private_pod', '~> 1.2.3'
```

When I update the repo on my new private pod `pod repo update`, everything works fine and I see the pod successfully install & can view the files in my project.

However, the problem lies with trying to lint the new pod with the end goal of publishing it.

```
 -> my_new_private_pod (0.0.1)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `my_private_pod (~> 1.2.3)` depended upon by `my_new_private_pod`

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
) during validation.

[!] my_new_private_pod did not pass validation, due to 1 error.
```

As mentioned above:

1. I did update my repo & confirmed expected files
2. Verified all version data. This included copying the text directly from the `Podfile` that works into the `Podspec` that does not
3. The repo is present in the `Podfile` & confirmed by installing the pod successfully into the example target

I did take a few extra steps as well.

- Deleted derived data
- `pod deintegrate` and reinstall
- Restarted Xcode
- Threw things at computer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I modified my `lint` command to the following and now it works:

```
pod lib lint --sources=my_repo,trunk
```

Apparently, you have to provide the private repo to the `lint` command with the `--sources` flag.

In my case, `my_repo` is needed to include my private repo, while `trunk` is required to include public pods. Combining the two makes cocoapods happy.